# How do you take a random stringed word and turn each letter into a variable

Tags: python, string, list, variables

I want to take a random word which is a string and turn that string into a list of variables with each letter being a variable. Then multiply each variable together to get a value. For example

```
a, b, c, d = 2, 3, 5, 7
word = "bad"
wrd = list(word)
```

wrd would give me wrd = ('b' , 'a' , 'd')
but what i want is  wrd = (b,a,d) = (3,2,7) so that i can do something along the lines of

```
value = wrd[0]*wrd[1]*wrd[2]
```

I also need value = 42 to still be related to "bad"

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Don't generate variable names; use a dictionary instead:

```
values = {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 5, 'd': 7}

value = 1
for char in word:
    value *= values[char]
```

It is *much simpler* to look up a key in a dictionary than it is to dynamically look up names in your local or global namespace.

Demo:

```
>>> values = {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 5, 'd': 7}
>>> word = 'bad'
>>> value = 1
>>> for char in word:
...     value *= values[char]
... 
>>> value
42
```

You can generate an inverse mapping from primes back to letters too:

```
inverse = {prime: char for char, prime in values.items()}
```

so that if you calculate the prime factors of the value you can at least reconstruct the characters used for a given value (but not the order).

Comment: will this work for a few thousand words too? I have to get a value for each word that are all in a list toegether

Comment: @BobUnger: Why wouldn't it? It'll work *far better* with a dictionary than with local names, for starters.